# URl rewrite automatically for anchor tag onclick

Tags: php, url-rewrite-module

url redirect for my anchor tag  or onclick 
url is

```
http://localhost/re/jobs/view_jobs.php?id=14
```

how could i write url rewrite for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to use the id:

```
EDIT:
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^jobs/([0-9]+)?$ view_jobs.php?id=$1
```

This basically says 
^(starts with)re/jobs/
then ([0-9]+) - any number

?$ - end of query

directs to view_jobs.php?id=$1 ($1 = first regex)

And the anchor tag would be

```
http://localhost/re/jobs/14
```

Or if you wanted to use the job title for SEO purposes

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^jobs/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)?$ view_jobs.php?name=$1
```

And the anchor tag would be

```
http://localhost/re/jobs/jobname
```

Comment: This comment list is too long and hard to read code, open a new question and link me to it here

Comment: Indeed - @user2610240 please avoid extended discussions in an answer's comments.